# Ставится ли в данном предложении запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, и

**В итоге закружилась голова(?) и я чуть не упала в обморок.**
Если не ставится, то почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**В итоге закружилась голова и я чуть не упала в обморок.**

Запятая между простыми предложениями в составе ССП не ставится, если они имеют **общий элемент** (в данном случае это обстоятельство ***в итоге***).